# Ambiguity of the notation $\lhd$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

If a group $G$ have two subgroups $A,B$ which are isomorphic. Can I say that  $A\lhd G$ if $B\lhd G$?
Indeed we often do in this way when we don't considerate about the concrete set of groups.

Comment: Think about the dihedral group of order 8.

Comment: The triangle points the other way: if $N$ is a (proper) normal subgroup of $G$, write $N\lhd G$, not $N\rhd G$.

Comment: As an above counterexample shows, the answer generally is no. I think what you are referring to is situations like $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\trianglelefteq\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ where we mean $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. This is an abuse of notation and should only be used when it is very clear what the author means.

Comment: @Hugo: You are right if the isomorphism between $A$ and $B$ comes via an automorphism of $G$.